# Lua: how do I split a string (of a varying length) into multiple parts?

Tags: string, lua, split

I have a string, starting with a number, then a space, then a word of an unknown amount of letters, a space again, and then **sometimes** another piece of text (which may or may not contain more than one word).

**EDIT: the last piece of text is sometimes left out (see example #2)
Using the methods mentioned in the comments, str:find(...) on #2 would return nil.**

Example:

```
"(number) (text) [more text]"
1: "10 HELLO This is a string"
2: "88 BYE"
```

What I want is to split these strings into a table, inside a table containing more of these split strings, like this:

```
{
  [(number)] = { [1] = (text), [2] = (more text) }
  [10] = { [1] = "HELLO", [2] = "This is a string" }
}
```

I have tried several methods, but none of them give me the desired result.
One of the methods I tried, for example, was splitting the string on whitespaces. But that resulted in:

```
{
  [10] = { [1] = "HELLO", [2] = "This", ... [4] = "string" }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using various Lua [string patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1), achieving the desired result is quite easy.

For eg.

```
function CustomMatching( sVar )
    local tReturn = {}
    local _, _, iNumber, sWord, sRemain = sVar:find( "^(%d+)%s(%a+)%s(.+)" )
    tReturn[tonumber(iNumber)] = { sWord, sRemain }
    return tReturn
end
```

And to call it:

```
local sVar = "10 HELLO This is a string"
local tMyTable = CustomMatching( sVar )
```

---

In the `find()` method the pattern `"^(%d+)%s(%a+)%s(.+)"` means:

- Find and store all digits(`%d`) until a space is encountered.
- Find and store all letters(`%a`) until a space is encountered.
- Find and store all characters until the end of string is reached.

---

### EDIT

Changed `tReturn[iNumber]` to `tReturn[tonumber(iNumber)]` as per the discussion in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508474/lua-how-do-i-split-a-string-into-multiple-parts-with-a-different-length/15510435?noredirect=1#comment21966842_15510435).

Comment: `tReturn[10] ~= tReturn["10"]`

Comment: `%d` will itself take numbers, otherwise return nil. @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: What is your `type(iNumber)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`string.match`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.match) method with an appropriate [pattern](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1):

```
local n, w, str = ('10 HELLO This is a string'):match'^(%d+)%s+(%S+)%s+(.*)$'
your_table[tonumber(n)] = {w, str}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer a bit?

Comment: @nneonneo - Look [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.match) and [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1)

Comment: I mean, for the sake of improving your answer. It will make for a better answer if you explain why your code will work when the original code did not.

Comment: @nneonneo - OP didn't show his original code, so comparison is not available.  My code doesn't require explanations as it's straightforward.

Comment: I edited it a bit, see what I mean? I think you should further explain the pattern (why it works). Straightforward to you may not be straightforward to someone who is just learning Lua.

Comment: @nneonneo - Do you really think my answer should contain tutorial on Lua?

Comment: No, of course I do not expect a tutorial! But, see Dream Eater's nice answer -- it shows code, but also shows some reasoning and explanation. You do not need a tutorial, but you do need to provide more explanation than simply a few lines of code.

Comment: @nneonneo - IMO, good answer is short answer.  Nobody wants to read long texts.  Good answer should be free of excessive lines of code and redundant explanatory text.